# If i try to hook two functions into one loop the display breaks, woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce in Wordpress and trying to add extra information to each product in the shop display (archive products).

I am trying to add an add to cart button, and some extra attributes.

I can easily add the cart button with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );
```

and I can add the attribute with a function i have saved with this

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'isa_woo_get_one_pa', 21);
```

Each work on their own but if I try to do both it causes chaos on the display of the products.

Here is the cart button inserted successfully on it's own:
[Cart button only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXg5P.png)

Here is the cart and attribute together:
[Cart and attribute together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41wGd.png)

The total code I have in my functions.php is as follows:

```
/**
* WooCommerce: Show only one custom product attribute above Add-to-cart button on single product page.
*/
function isa_woo_get_one_pa(){

    // Edit below with the title of the attribute you wish to display
    $desired_att = 'Gauge';

    global $product;
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    if ( ! $attributes ) {
        return;
    }

    $out = '';

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

        if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

            // sanitize the desired attribute into a taxonomy slug
            $tax_slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '_', $desired_att)));

            // if this is desired att, get value and label
            if ( $attribute['name'] == 'pa_' . $tax_slug ) {

                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute['name'], 'all' );
                // get the taxonomy
                $tax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
                // get the tax object
                $tax_object = get_taxonomy( $tax );
                // get tax label
                if ( isset ( $tax_object->labels->singular_name ) ) {
                    $tax_label = $tax_object->labels->singular_name;
                } elseif ( isset( $tax_object->label ) ) {
                    $tax_label = $tax_object->label;
                    // Trim label prefix since WC 3.0
                    if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label, 'Product ' ) ) {
                       $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, 8 );
                    }
                }

                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                $out .= '<span class="attribute-label">' . $tax_label . ': </span> ';
                $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">' . $term->name . '</span></li>';

                }           

            } // our desired att

        } else {

            // for atts which are NOT registered as taxonomies

            // if this is desired att, get value and label
            if ( $attribute['name'] == $desired_att ) {
                $out .= $attribute['name'] . ': ';
                $out .= $attribute['value'];
            }
        }       


    }

    echo $out;
}
//add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'isa_woo_get_one_pa', 21);

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot that what display your are getting after placing the code?

Comment: @AhmedGinani I have added screenshots of before and after. Thanks.